# Error when parsing XML on Android 2.3.3

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to parse Xml, it worked on Android 4.3, but not on Android 2.3.3. It crushes, when reaches russian symbols. I tried to set encoding (parser.setInput(in, "windows-1251")), but it didn't worked (org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: unknown encoding)

Any help would be lovely. Thanks

XMLParser.class

```
public class XMLParser {
    private static final String ns = null;
    private String startTag;
    private String itemTag;
    private List<String> tags;

public XMLParser(String startTag, String itemTag, List<String> tags) {
    this.startTag = startTag;
    this.itemTag = itemTag;
    this.tags = tags;
}

public List<List<Map.Entry<String,String>>> parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException, ParseException {
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);
        return readFeed(parser);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}

private List<List<Map.Entry<String,String>>> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException, ParseException {
    List<List<Map.Entry<String,String>>> entries = new ArrayList();
    parser.nextTag();
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, startTag);
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        // Starts by looking for the entry tag
        Item item = new Item(itemTag,tags);
        if (name.equals(itemTag)) {
            entries.add(item.readItem(parser));
        } else {
            item.skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return entries;
}
}
```

DownloadXml uses XmlParser

```
public class DownloadXml extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList> {

    private ArrayList loadXmlFromNetwork(String urlString) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        // Instantiate the parser
        Log.d(log, startTag);
        XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser(startTag,itemTag,tags);
        List<List<Map.Entry<String,String>>> entries = null;


        try {
            stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
            entries = xmlParser.parse(stream);
            // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
            // finished using it.
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        }
       return entriesHandling(entries);
    }
}
}
```

XML i am trying to parse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<answer>
<item>
   <path>1</path>
   <user_name>Иван Иванович</user_name>
   <ID>1112</ID>
   <person_id>1111</person_id>
</item>
</answer>
```

Logs

```
10-01 07:50:17.470    1604-1604/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host 
Connection established 0x8ce7cf0, tid 1604
10-01 07:50:20.270    1604-1604/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ No keyboard for id 0
10-01 07:50:20.270    1604-1604/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-01 07:50:27.520    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 D/xmlOuterLogs﹕ answer
10-01 07:50:27.940    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ Error parsing document. (position:line -1, column -1) caused by: org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 5, column 16: not well-formed (invalid token); nested exception is:
10-01 07:50:27.940    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 5, column 16: not well-formed (invalid token)
10-01 07:50:27.940    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.append(ExpatParser.java:466)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatPullParser$ByteDocument.flush(ExpatPullParser.java:956)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatPullParser$Document.pump(ExpatPullParser.java:769)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatPullParser$Document.dequeue(ExpatPullParser.java:813)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatPullParser.next(ExpatPullParser.java:302)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatPullParser.nextTag(ExpatPullParser.java:338)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.ellina.pg_test3.Parser.XMLParser.readFeed(XMLParser.java:40)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.ellina.pg_test3.Parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:32)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.ellina.pg_test3.DownloadXmlOuter$DownloadXml.loadXmlFromNetwork(DownloadXmlOuter.java:83)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.ellina.pg_test3.DownloadXmlOuter$DownloadXml.doInBackground(DownloadXmlOuter.java:53)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.ellina.pg_test3.DownloadXmlOuter$DownloadXml.doInBackground(DownloadXmlOuter.java:46)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-01 07:50:27.950    1604-1621/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-01 08:24:00.150    1666-1666/com.example.ellina.pg_test3 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8cea448, tid 1666
```

Comment: could you print the logcat?

Comment: What's in the logcat?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and did u try with UTF-16?

Comment: UTF-16 didn't helped

Comment: check the character encoding for your zone and change it accordingly http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/CharEncoding.html